# VBA Class Module - Setting default values

Tags: vba, excel

I've only just started wrapping my head around building classes in Class Modules for VBA. It has been fairly smooth sailing so far, but I ran into a small challenge which is very easily solved if I were making a conventional function in a Module: How can I set an optional boolean default value to True?

In a function or sub, I would simply solve this in the property list by implicit declaration:

```
Function SomeFunction(Optional bValue = True) as Variant
...
End Function
```

In a Class Module using Let and Get properties, I haven't quite found my way around it yet since VBA defaultedly declares a Boolean variable as false. So I have, e.g.:

```
Private bValue as Boolean

Public Property Let TrueOrFalse(myBoolProperty As Boolean)
    bValue = myBoolProperty
End Property

Private Property Get TrueOrFalse() As Boolean
    TrueOrFalse = bValue
End Property

Function SomeFunction() As Boolean
    SomeFunction = TrueOrFalse
End Function
```

Bear in mind, I'm still learning, so even this simple code might be unsexy to the trained eye, but the question remains: How can I default bValue to True if I only want to use it as an Optional property?

Hopefully that made some sense..

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I highly suggest if you haven't looked into VSTO that you do. You can create add in's for excel, outlook, word, etc using C# and VB.net. I find VBA to be very difficult to work with things like arrays are more complicated than they need to be and they are really easy to do with C# or VB.net

Comment: If you want your properties to have some specific default value then you can set that in `class_initialize` - for example set `bValue` to True

Comment: Thank you for the tip and advice. I know you're right and I should delve into VSTO sooner rather than later..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Class_Initialize method will allow you to set default values.

I set up my properties like:

```
Option Explicit
Dim pTrueOrFalse as Boolean

'## This method will be invoked whenever you create a class object using the NEW keyword/etc.
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pTrueOrFalse = True
End Sub

'## Property "Get" method, which returns the value when called
Public Property Get TrueOrFalse() As Boolean
    TrueOrFalse = pTrueOrFalse
End Property

'## Property "Let" method, which assigns the value when called
Public Property Let TrueOrFalse(lTrueOrFalse as Boolean)
    pTrueOrFalse = lTrueOrFalse
End Property
```

When using these in your regular code, you can do something like:

```
Dim myClassObject as New [class object name]   'this will invoke the Initialize procedure

MsgBox myClassObject.TrueOrFalse  'this will call upon the "Get" method

myClassObject.TrueOrFalse = False 'This will call upon the "Let" method

MsgBox myClassObject.TrueOrFalse
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the "Class" in `Class_Initialize` is a constant value and does _not_ resemble the actual name of the class. I.e. it is always called `Class_Initialize`, even if my class name is "Car" or "Fruit". Right?

Comment: @DavidZemens this is super old now, but isn't it bad practice to set your internal property variables as public?

Comment: @Jaberwocky yeah, that should probably not be public scoped :)